# Не отображаются TextInputs

Tags: qt, qml

Работаю в QtCreator, разрабатываю приложение под Sailfish OS. У меня есть QML-файл:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Sailfish.Silica 1.0

Page {

    id: page
    allowedOrientations: Orientation.All

    SilicaFlickable {
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight: column.height

        Column {
            id: column
            spacing: Theme.paddingLarge

            TextField {
                placeholderText: qsTr("Fill the field")
                label: qsTr("Text Field")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И при этом не отображается TextField. Так же не отображаются и остальные элементы инпута. В чём может быть причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена. Необходимо было указать ширину Column.